# How to prepend a character to start of each line in 250,000+ line file using a script?

Tags: applescript, command-line, bash, automator, zsh

I have text file with 250,000 lines - and I need to append the same single character at the start of each line. I have tried to use various multiline /column edit plugins in Atom and Sublime but they just hang - I guess due to size of file.

Is this something I could do with with a bash/zsh script - or AppleScript/Automator maybe ?

Answer (score 10):

Prepend each line of a file with a capital A and write a new file-

```
awk '{print "A"$0}' < FILE > NEWFILE
```

Comment: The `<` before `FILE ` is not necessary.

Comment: [What is the difference between “cat < filename” and “cat filename”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190700/what-is-the-difference-between-cat-filename-and-cat-filename)

Comment: @ankii So basically "wildcards" and "permissions".

Answer (score 9):

To prepend `X` to the start of every line of `file`, writing to `newfile`, in Terminal:

```
sed 's/^/X/' file > newfile
```

Here I'm using `sed`, the Unix stream editor, to use a very simple [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to **s**ubstitute the beginning of every line (the `^` symbol) with an X.

Comment: As an extension to this solution, using `sed -i'.bak' 's/^/X/' file` will create a backup of the original file (with specified extension `file.bak`) and then the substitution is applied in-place.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that someone would down vote an answer that is shown as an example in the venerable sed one liners.  Any mods out there?????

Comment: Did someone downvote it, @fd0? I didn't see that. I suppose if one had a Classic-style text file with CRs as newlines this (and all the other shell examples) would misbehave.

Answer (score 2):

The stream editor `sed` is likely the fastest and sharpest tool built for exactly this task.

Use the insert command (the newline after `\` is part of the syntax):

```
sed 'i\
X' file > newfile
```

---

```
$ time sed 'i\                     
X' line250000 >/dev/null

real    0m0.118s
user    0m0.102s
sys     0m0.012s
```

The delay or overhead for this operation is extremely low making it very efficient for huge files.

Comment: Writing to _disk file_, and using `sudo purge` in between, your version verses `sed 's/^/X/' file > newfile` was only `0.021s` faster in my testing, and hardly worth considering it as an option to the _single line regexp_ `sed` _command_  for me as I find it easier to write the _single line regexp_ `sed` _command_. That said, either of the two `sed` answers was no less then `1.224s` faster than the `awk` _command_ to achieve the same goal. Go `sed`! 

Comment: @user3439894 Disk write time basically is the `sys` part of the measured time, processing time the `user` part. I see about 70% more processing time for the regexp version here, but would agree that it doesn't really matter unless one needs to process a huge number of files with a huge number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

This `bash` snippet will prepend each line of a file with a hash (`#`) and save it to a new file:

```bsh
IFS=$'\r\n'; printf '#%s\n' $(</path/to/file.txt) > /path/to/newfile.txt
```

**Explanation**

- **`IFS=$'\r\n'`:** This sets the field separator so that only the characters `\r` (carriage return) and `\n` (newline) are used to delimit a string. The default setting can be restored using: `IFS=$' \t\n'`
- **`printf`:** This is a builtin command in `bash` that is used to format text according to the pattern supplied as the first argument.  In this case, `#%s\n` tells it to format every subsequent argument as a regular string (`%s`), before which it will print a hash character and after which it will print a newline.
- **`$(</path/to/file.txt)`:** This is a command substitution that uses an input redirection to supply it the contents of a file path.  It's equivalent to `$(cat /path/to/file.txt)`, without having to call out to `cat`.
- **`>`:**  This redirects the output of the previous command, i.e. `printf`, so that it is written to the file at the specified file path.  If your file paths contain spaces, either escape each space using a preceding backslash (`\`), or surround the file path with double quotes, making sure anything you want the shell to expand sits outside of the quotes, e.g. `~/Documents/My\ Massive\ File.txt` *or* `~/"My Massive File.txt"`

Comment: Does this work with files > 250‘000 lines? `$(<` might produce a lot of data here

Comment: @nohillside It does.  I created a file with 412,740 lines, each of 80 characters length.  This method performed the task in `bash 4.4` in under 8 seconds (processor: Intel Core i5 2.40Ghz).  During its run, it used approximately 0.6% of the available memory at a constant rate (total RAM: 8.00GB).  I compared it to a buffered input/output solution (using `while` and  `read`).   Whilst this solution achieved the same desired outcome, and obviously used approximately 0.0% memory per unit time, those units of time were too many to sit through: after 2 minutes, it had 96816 lines left to process.